# Splitting with exception in python

Tags: python

```
Mt. Everest is the highest peak in the world. It's height is 8848 m.
```

How do I split this into two sentences? and not split it on the dot besides 'Mt'? Rule is whenever Mt is followed by a dot, it needs to skip that.

Something like this:

```
Mt. Everest is the highest peak in the world. 
It's height is 8848 m.
```

Code so far

```
data = "Mt. Everest is the highest peak in the world. It's height is 8848 m."
sentences=data.split(".")
print (sentences)
```

Comment: Where's the code you have written so far?

Comment: Do you have any idea about regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind to avoid splitting when dot comes after `Mt`.

```
 re.split('(?<!Mt)\. ', s)
```

**Code**:

```
>>> s = "Mt. Everest is the highest peak in the world. It's height is 8848 m."
>>> re.split('(?<!Mt)\. ', s)
['Mt. Everest is the highest peak in the world', "It's height is 8848 m"]
```